# Error: roundoff error is detected in the extrapolation table

Tags: r, mean, probability-density

For the resolution of an exercise at college Im asked to get de expected value of density distribution like this: B(X)=75*X-200.

Im trying to get it in R, but when I try to integrate the function from -Inf to Inf it displays the error:

*Error in integrate(integrarFuncDens, lower = -Inf, upper = Inf) :
roundoff error is detected in the extrapolation table*

the code:

```
integrarFuncDens <- function(x) {x*(75*x-200)}
media <- integrate(integrarFuncDens, lower=-Inf, upper=Inf)
```

Anyone knows why?

Comment: `integrate` can't calculate the integral of your function between -Inf and Inf because it is infinite. This function is _not_ a probability density function. If the support was limited from -0.2714418 to +0.2714418 then it would be: `integrate(integrarFuncDens, lower=-0.2714418, upper=0.2714418)` returns `1`, or perhaps a lower limit of 0 and upper limit of 4.002496883, since `integrate(integrarFuncDens, lower= 0, upper=4.002496883)` is also 1

Comment: That doesn't seem like a proper density function at least not over the range -Inf to Inf. The area of a density function over it's range should be 1. Your current integral does not converge. You probably need to identify the correct domain of support.

Comment: Okey, now I see it, but I have a new error. To get you in context, the question goes like this: 
If the benefit in euros per hour of a photovoltaic installation is given by
the expression B(X)=75*X-200, calculate the expectation and the variance of the benefit. Then, I concluded that the interval must be from 0 to inf (as the instalation can be producing from no time to infinite, but this error shows up: the integral is probably divergent.

Comment: if you are looking at benefit in euros 'per hour', why don't you ask yourself about the 'daily' expectation and the variance of the daily benefit ? a machine might operate for between 0 and 24 hours of a day.